# i am trying to create a model that saves array of products to sqlite databse using sequelize but it's not working

Tags: arrays, express, sqlite, sequelize.js

products: {
type: DataTypes.STRING,
allowNull: false,
set(val: string[]) {
return this.setDataValue('products', JSON.stringify(val));
},
get() {
return JSON.parse(this.getDataValue('products'));
},
},

This is what i did but its not working

products: {
type: DataTypes.STRING,
allowNull: false,
set(val: string[]) {
return this.setDataValue('products', JSON.stringify(val));
},
get() {
return JSON.parse(this.getDataValue('products'));
},
},

Comment: Hi, welcome. "it's not working" doesn't help other to answer. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ,  [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thank you